# Setting selectedvalue for a dropdownlist in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a dropdownlist in my Gridview and I am binding a datasource to the gridview.

Though all the records are displaying properly the dropdown value is not selected.

How do I set something like

`<%# Bind("Country") %>`  for a dropdownlist in the Gridview in ASP.net.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook into the RowDataBound event for the grid view, find the control and set the value.

```
protected void gridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

     var dropdownList = e.Row.FindControl("YOUR_DROP_DOWN") as DropDownList;
     dropdownList .SelectedIndex = SET_VALUE_HERE;

}
```

Comment: Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

        Dim dl As DropDownList = CType(e.Row.FindControl("ddlDecision"), DropDownList)
        Dim atviolPK As TextBox = CType(e.Row.FindControl("txtViolationPK"), TextBox)
        dl.SelectedValue = GetDecisionCode(atviolPK.Text)
    End Sub
For some reason both dl and actviolPK are showing as nothing. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Setting DropDownList value from a Datasource should be like:

```
    protected void gridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
        DropDownList ddlCountry = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCountry");
        ddlCountry.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Country").ToString();
     }
    }
```