# Acessing Dropdownlist(selected value) in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a bit of trouble with getting dropdownlist selected value we have in aspx a Gridview and in it dropdownlist:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid1" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="true" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="something" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="filtras">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown1" runat="server"
                    OnLoad="dropdownLoad"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="updatetable" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

We fill the `DropDownList` with values using `OnLoad` event, and then when we select something from the `DropDownList`, the event `OnSelectedIndexChange` should allow us to take the selected value and to do what we want with it (filter the grid in this case), but `OnSelectedIndexChange` never gets executed.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //Create Gridview + fill with values
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        return;
    }

    ArrayList mycountries = new ArrayList();
    mycountries.Add("Norway");
    mycountries.Add("Sweden");
    mycountries.Add("France");
    mycountries.Add("Italy");
    mycountries.TrimToSize();
    mycountries.Sort();

    rb.DataSource = mycountries;
    rb.DataBind();

    grid1.DataSource = mycountries;
    grid1.DataBind();
}

protected void dropdownLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   // fill dropDownList in GridView with data
    DropDownList dropdown = sender as DropDownList;
    if (dropdown != null)
    {
        ArrayList mycountries = new ArrayList();
        mycountries.Add("Norway");
        mycountries.Add("Sweden");
        mycountries.Add("France");
        mycountries.Add("Italy");
        mycountries.TrimToSize();
        mycountries.Sort();

        dropdown.DataSource = mycountries;
        dropdown.DataBind();

        TextBox1.Text = dropdown.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }
}

protected void updatetable(object sender, EventArgs e)
{// after dropDownList element was selected change dropdownlist values/or filter the table...
 //this part is never executed ! Why?

    DropDownList dropdown = sender as DropDownList;
    if (dropdown != null)
    {
        ArrayList mycountries = new ArrayList();
        mycountries.Add("UK");
        mycountries.Add("USA");
        mycountries.Add("Sweden");
        mycountries.Add("Hungary");
        mycountries.TrimToSize();
        mycountries.Sort();

        dropdown.DataSource = mycountries;
        dropdown.DataBind();
    }
}
```

How can I get the `DropDownList`'s selected value? My debugger shows that `OnSelectedIndexChange` is never executed.
I tried following the suggestions in this question [Setting selectedvalue for a dropdownlist in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867499/setting-selectedvalue-for-a-dropdownlist-in-gridview), but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting AutoPostBack to true for your dropdown control so that it causes a postback?

Comment: you are my hero! thx you so much as a return gift i'll give u a cool pic ;)   http://www.cha.lt/uploads/posts/2011-11/1320474024_15.jpg  http://www.cha.lt/category/paveiksliukai/66617-o-koks-jusu-megstamiausias-pesonazas.html

Comment: Glad to help. love the first image, perfect randomness!